# MySQL : Get name after registered name

Tags: mysql, database, select, syntax

I have a table called `USER` consist of `UserID`, `Name`, and the `Date` registered.
I would like to get information as below :

`UserID`, `Name`, `Date`, `User Registered After`

Is `MySQL DB` able to retrieve the `User Registered After` column?

Answer (score 0):

If you can, you probably will want remove those spaces from your column names.  You can get around it by escaping the column name, for example to get just the column `User Registered After`:

```
SELECT `User Registered After` FROM `USER`;
```

You should also avoid using keywords and reserved words such as DATE for your column names and/or table names.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html

Comment: I'm sorry if it looks like not clear enough. In USER table, the column user_registered_after doesn't exist. It's something that I need to add. My point is, for example, I have Deryl (registered as user on 12 May), then I have Gio (13 May). Then I need a record like below

USER {
UserID(1),
Name(Deryl),
DateRegister(12-May),
user_registered_after(Gio)}

I wonder the logic to find Gio in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve this,

```
    SELECT
        u.UserId, u.Name, u.Date,
        (
            SELECT u2.Name
            FROM USER u2
            WHERE u2.Date > u.Date
            ORDER BY u2.Date LIMIT 1
        ) AS UserResiteredAfter
    FROM USER u
    WHERE u.UserId = 1
```